# Use pathExtension from Array as TableViewCell Image Source

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am displaying the Documents folder in a table view and now I want to make the picture the symbol of the suffix.

For example, if the name is "test.pdf", I want to display the pdf.png from the assets.

```
arrayDocuments = ["0.pdf", "1.pdf", "2.png", "3.jpg", "4.zip"]
```

I tried to use `= UIImage(named: arrayDocuments[indexPath.row])` and
`= UIImage(named: (arrayDocuments[indexPath.row] as NSString).pathExtension)` but `.pathExtension` only allows NSString so I tried to convert the Array to NSArray as shown below but it didn't work either.

```
let nsa = NSArray(array: arrayDocuments)
if arrayDocuments[indexPath.row].hasSuffix("") {
} else {
    cell.mySymbol.image = UIImage(named: (nsa[indexPath.row] as! NSString).pathExtension)
}
```

Comment: Write a switch statement based on the file extension and assign the appropriate image

Comment: @user1046037 This question is asking how to get the file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to convert the array to an `NSArray`.

You can cast your String to NSString if you wish to call `pathExtension`.

```
let filename = arrayDocuments[indexPath.row]
let ext = (filename as NSString).pathExtension
if ext.isEmpty {
    cell.mySymbol.image = nil
} else {
    cell.mySymbol.image = UIImage(named: ext)
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks. I already tried something similar before but didn't work somehow

Answer (score 0):

pathextension will return you only png or zip or jpg.

if you intending to display a pdf.png file; you might want to use Bundle Pathforresource to get the file and assign to your extension.

like below where your resource is your file name and type is your extension.

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "pdf", ofType: ext)
```

Comment: The question is asking how to get the extension part of the string. The question is not about how to get the image.